# Quelle est la différence entre demander et poser ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Quelle est la différence entre *demander* et *poser* ?

En anglais je sais qu'il y a une grande différence de ton entre *to ask a question* et *to pose a question*, mais en français, j'ai l'impression que les deux mots *demander* et *poser* sont interchangeables. C'est vrai ou pas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En français on **pose une question**, mais on ne demande pas une question, on **formule une demande** sous la forme d'une question.

Donc ici :

- vous avez demandé : *Quelle est la différence entre “demander” et “poser”?*
- et vous avez posé la question : *Quelle est la différence entre “demander” et “poser”?*

Answer (score 3):

On pose une question pour demander une réponse.

Comment: Ça devient un peu compliqué, mais Jeopardy est le seul cas où on demande une question :-)

Answer (score 1):

En français, "demander une question" c'est comme dire "hey est-ce que je peux avoir une question s'il vous plaît?".

Donc la réponse à "Est-ce que je peux te demander une question?" est "Oui, certainement, quel genre de question veux-tu?".

Et la réponse à "Est-ce que je peux te poser une question?" est "Oui certainement, quelle est ta question?".

C'est différent en anglais.  En anglais, "we ask a question".  En anglais on peut utiliser l'équivalent du verbe demander pour poser une question.  Mais pas en français.

Par contre, du moins au Québec, on peut entendre "demander une question" même de gens qui parlent bien français en général.  C'est-à-dire que même si c'est 100% une erreur de "demander une question" le fait d'entendre quelqu'un dire "demander une question" ne baissera pas vraiment sa crédibilité en termes de connaissance du français selon moi.

Answer (score 0):

Complément

On ne peut pas utiliser la forme « demander une question » mais on peut, cependant, dire « demander une réponse à une question » ; néanmoins ce n'est pas équivalent, il existe une légère différence et deux contextes importants.

1- Cette forme sert pour insister, après la question, sur le fait qu'une réponse n'a pas été donnée alors que normalement escomptée.

2- Elle sert aussi pour insister sur le fait, avant de poser la question, que la question ne peut pas rester sans réponse, que l'on exige une réponse.

> Monsieur le procureur, le témoin n'as pas eu le temps de s'exprimer; il n'est pas clair si oui ou non il était menacé ; je demande une réponse à cette question.
>
> En notre qualité de défenseurs des droits de l'homme, nous demandons une réponse à une question ; pourquoi cette situation connue des autorités a-t-elle été tolérée aussi longtemps?